# nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "include" directive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am learning how to deploy AWS for the first time. I am following this guide here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtWgb_vbyvY.

I am using windows machine while the person in the video uses mac.

I am getting the following error when running ngnix commands on the windows terminal: "nginx: [emerg] CreateFile() "C:/nginx-1.23.0/nginx-1.23.0/mime.types" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified) in C:\Users\Shi Jie\Downloads\nginx-1.23.0\nginx-1.23.0/conf/nginx.conf:12"

i think it is how i write the path on my ngnix.conf which i write as such

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include \Users\Shi Jie\Downloads\nginx-1.23.0\nginx-1.23.0\mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    client_body_buffer_size 100k;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 100k;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    keepalive_timeout 5 5;
    send_timeout 10;
    server_tokens off;
    #gzip  on; on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Can anyone point the way to teach me how to write the path properly? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `spaces`, `{` and `"`. So change your include line to the following:

```
...

include /Users/Shi\ Jie/Downloads/nginx-1.23.0/nginx-1.23.0/mime.types;

...
```